# Grouping using a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analysis

I am getting stuck in one of the part where i am trying to groupby maximum 'Data Value' according to the Period, only if the 'Year' is '15'. It is the dataframe screenshot.

[image]

The period/index is varying like this :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.dataFrame([01-01 , 28 , 05], [01-01 , 23 , 15] , [01-01 , 30 , 
15][02-01 , 24 , 05], [02-01 , 28 , 15], columns = [Period, Data_Value, 
Year])
```

The output should return 
[01-01 , 30 , 15] and [02-01 , 28 , 15]

Comment: It would help if you could show what is the expected output for your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
out = df.loc[df['Year'] == 15, 'Data_value'].max(level=0)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering, I think i wasn't clear with the screenshot that i have posted. Let me reframe the question.

Comment: @MohitYadav - Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.